# Open File Dialog running twice repeatedly

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt5, openfiledialog

I tried to open two different types of files with `QFileDialog` in PyQt5 for pandas dataframe but it open repeatedly twice for each files before executed. However, when I'm using specific file only 'filename' it will directly executed once.

It's opened twice using this code:

```
class dataframe(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(dataframe, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        canvas = mycanvas(self)
        layout.addWidget(canvas)

        self.btn3 = QPushButton("Plot")
        self.btn3.clicked.connect(canvas.PlotChart)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn3)


    def input(self):
        lasdata = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open LAS', r'data/', "LAS files (*.las)")[0]
        textdata = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open Text', r'data/', "Text files (*.txt)")[0]

        l = lasio.read(f"{lasdata}")
        data = l.df()
        data = data.replace('-999.00000', np.nan)
        data.index.names = ['DEPT']
        w = l.well.WELL.value
        data['WELL'] = w


        text = pd.read_csv(f"{textdata}", sep='\t')
        text_unit = text['RU'].unique()

        data_w = pd.DataFrame()
        for i in range(len(text_unit)):
            top = text.iloc[i]['D']
            if i < len(text_unit) - 1:
                bottom = text.iloc[i + 1]['D']
            else:
                bottom = int(round(data.tail(1).index.item()))
            data_int = data.iloc[top:bottom, :]
            data_int['INT'] = text.iloc[i]['RU']
            data_w = data_w.append(data_int)
        data = data_w

        return w, data


    def det(self, gr):
        w, data = dataframe.input(self)

        GR = data.iloc[:, gr]

        conditions = [
            (GR <= 60),
            (GR >= 60)]
        lit = ['A', 'B']
        data['L'] = np.select(conditions, lit, default='Undefined')
        return data


    def calculation(self):
        w, data = dataframe.input(self)
        data = dataframe.det(self, 1)

        data_well = pd.DataFrame()
        data_int = pd.DataFrame()
        F_w = pd.DataFrame()
        Fa = pd.DataFrame()
        text_unit = data['INT'].unique()

        for i in range(len(text_unit)):
            data_int = data.where(data['INT'] == text_unit[i]).dropna()
            F_percent = data_int['L'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
            F_percent = F_percent.sort_index()
            F_percent['INT'] = text_unit[i]
            F_percent = pd.DataFrame(F_percent).transpose()
            F_w = F_w.append(F_percent)
        F_w['W'] = w
        Fa = Fa.append(F_w)
        F_w = pd.DataFrame()

        Fa = Fa.reset_index()
        Fa = Fa.fillna(0)

        return Fa


class mycanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, dpi=120):
        self.fig = plt.Figure(dpi=dpi)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)

    def PlotChart(self):
        outputs = dataframe.calculation(self)  # .where(Fa['W']==well)
        int = outputs['INT'].unique()

        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.set_title("AA")
        outputs.plot.barh(x='INT', stacked=True, ax=self.axes)
        self.axes.set_yticks(range(len('INT')), 'INT')
        self.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = dataframe()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, it's directly executed once with this code:

```
        def Input(self):
                lasdata = 'data/AA.las'
                textdata = 'data/AATEXT.txt'
            
                l = lasio.read(lasdata)
                data = l.df()
            
                text = pd.read_csv(textdata, sep='\t')
```

Is there something wrong with File Dialog code, as with the lower code (direct name) it successfully executed once, but with the file dialog it opened twice before read the next codes. I need to make the GUI app so I need to use the file dialog.

This is part of the code with the two buttons:

```
    self.btn1 = QPushButton("LAS File")
    self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.las)
    self.btn2 = QPushButton("Text File")
    self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.text)
    self.btn3 = QPushButton("Plot")
    self.btn3.clicked.connect(canvas.PlotChart)
    layout.addWidget(self.btn1)
    layout.addWidget(self.btn2)
    layout.addWidget(self.btn3)


def las(self):
    self.lasfile = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open LAS', r'data/', "LAS files (*.las)")[0]

def text(self):
    self.textfile = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open Text', r'data/', "Text files (*.txt)")[0]

def input(self):
    lasdata = self.lasfile
    textdata = self.textfile

    l = lasio.read(f"{lasdata}")
    data = l.df()
    data = data.replace('-999.00000', np.nan)
    data.index.names = ['DEPT']
    w = l.well.WELL.value
    data['WELL'] = w


    text = pd.read_csv(f"{textdata}", sep='\t')
    text_unit = text['RU'].unique()
```

I try to make it into two buttons but it can't be opened or exit fail to be executed.

```
below is one of the text format 
WN  RU  D
AA  SR  19
AA  TF  50
AA  PSU 1700
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: You're calling `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName` twice so it will open a file dialog twice.

Comment: will this las file and txt file will always have the same name like name_of_file.las and name_of_file.txt ?

Comment: @Heike it's four times, twice for each files. I supposed to call it twice as it is different types of file..

Comment: @AdhunThalekkara no, it doesn't have to be the same name

Comment: tried to replicate its only opening twice. As a suggestion u could make two separate buttons for selecting these different files. can u share the Mainwindow also

Comment: @AdhunThalekkara I try to separate buttons as I show in edit but it can't be opened. how to replicate

Comment: can you share your full code or minimum reproducible code. you are are using a parent class like MainWindow and FROM_MAIN it will be help full if u share a minimum reproducible code.

Comment: Your question is a bit confused. How is `input` called? Also, what about that `selftopspath` (without any dot), which seems a typo that could cause a syntax error?

Comment: @AdhunThalekkara I've edited into the full code and change it to QWidget so it doesn't have to use specific ui file. I try two version, one without separate button and one with it.

Comment: @musicamante I revised the code, but it was not because of typo before. I fail to call the las and text in the separate version. And when the open file dialog inside input function,, it opened double for each file.

Comment: @maias please edit your code and ensure that it's **both** minimal *and* reproducible. Read the link in the first comment. We **must** be able to copy, paste and run your code without any substantial modification.

Comment: When you call `dataframe.calculation()` you are calling `dataframe.input` twice: once directly and once via `dataframe.det`.

Comment: the part of code u shared is still not reproducible try to run only the shared part of your code with a new file. so please update with minimum reproducible code

Comment: @Heike thank you, after checking it too that's where the problem is. still working on it, gonna try using self function and recheck the functions..